# is landlord responsible for damage that's not his fault?

Tags: landlord

My apartment had a toxic contamination issue. It wasn't my fault or the landlord's (in fact, it happened before he owned the building).

Some of my belongings had to be disposed of. Is he responsible for replacing them?

Comment: We will need more information, at least your jurisdiction.

Comment: What does your lease state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you live and also the details of your lease agreement. But in most cases, it is the landlord's responsibility to make sure the home you're living in is safe for you to live in (even conditions that existed before he owned the building). So in most cases yes, he would be responsible for replacing them (but again, this depends on where you live and the terms of your lease)

Comment: @ColleenV Generally not, real estate is one of the few areas of the law where caveat emptor still applies. If the seller had deliberately hidden the contamination then the buyer may have a case but generally not otherwise. Also, various pollution laws may make the polluter responsible for clean-up.

Comment: My understanding is that landlords are _not_ responsible for damage to the possessions of tenants.  (Hence the market for "renter insurance.")  Your last sentence to the contrary is a non-sequitur and could use some substantiation.

Comment: @dalem it depends on whether it could be considered a private nuisance, in which case _coming to the nuisance_ is not a valid defence for whoever caused it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not give the jurisdiction, however, just looking at common law.

What warranties did the landlord give in the lease about the condition of the property? Additionally, what warranties are read into the lease under local real estate or consumer protection laws? A general "fitness for purpose" warranty is virtually a given.

If there are warranties and the property did not meet those then you have a cause of action for breach of contract.

Notwithstanding your contractual position, you likely have a claim under the tort of negligence.